# Get name mangling when I try to use exceptions [CodeBlocks, C++]

Tags: c++, exception, name-mangling

I am trying to use exceptions for the first time 
but even though it is quite a simple example I
just cannot get it to compile, I have looked 
at several examples and tried coding it in 
many, many different ways
but I am still not even sure exactly where 
the problem is because I get namemangling 
when I introduce the catch/try/throw anyway
here is my code hopefully it is something 
really stupid :)

```
#include "Surface.h"
#include "SDL_Image.h"

using namespace std;

SDL_Surface* surface::Load(string fileName){

   SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = IMG_Load(fileName.c_str());
   if(loadedSurface == 0) throw 0;

   //Convert surface to same format as display
   loadedSurface = SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha(loadedSurface);

   return loadedSurface;
}
```

---

```
#include "GameState.h"
#include "Surface.h"

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

GameState::GameState(string fileName){

   try{
      stateWallpaper_ = surface::Load(fileName);
   }
   catch(int& e){
      cerr << "Could not load " << fileName << endl;
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to post the error message: It is

```
In function `ZN14GameStateIntroC1Ev':|
-undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'|
-undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'|
-undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'|
In function `ZN14GameStateIntroC1Ev':|
undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'|
In function `ZN14GameStateIntroC2Ev':|
-undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'|
-undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'|
-undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'|
obj\Release\GameStateIntro.o||In function `ZN14GameStateIntroC2Ev':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.5\ext\new_allocator.h|69|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'|
C:\MinGW\lib\libSDLmain.a(SDL_win32_main.o)||In function `redirect_output':|
\Users\slouken\release\SDL\SDL-1.2.15\.\src\main\win32\SDL_win32_main.c|219|undefined reference to `SDL_strlcpy'|
\Users\slouken\release\SDL\SDL-1.2.15\.\src\main\win32\SDL_win32_main.c|220|undefined reference to `SDL_strlcat'|
\Users\slouken\release\SDL\SDL-1.2.15\.\src\main\win32\SDL_win32_main.c|243|undefined reference to `SDL_strlcpy'|
\Users\slouken\release\SDL\SDL-1.2.15\.\src\main\win32\SDL_win32_main.c|244|undefined reference to `SDL_strlcat'|
C:\MinGW\lib\libSDLmain.a(SDL_win32_main.o)||In function `console_main':|
\Users\slouken\release\SDL\SDL-1.2.15\.\src\main\win32\SDL_win32_main.c|296|undefined reference to `SDL_strlcpy'|
\Users\slouken\release\SDL\SDL-1.2.15\.\src\main\win32\SDL_win32_main.c|301|undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'|
\Users\slouken\release\SDL\SDL-1.2.15\.\src\main\win32\SDL_win32_main.c|312|undefined reference to `SDL_SetModuleHandle'|
C:\MinGW\lib\libSDLmain.a(SDL_win32_main.o)||In function `WinMain@16':|
\Users\slouken\release\SDL\SDL-1.2.15\.\src\main\win32\SDL_win32_main.c|354|undefined reference to `SDL_getenv'|
\Users\slouken\release\SDL\SDL-1.2.15\.\src\main\win32\SDL_win32_main.c|386|undefined reference to `SDL_strlcpy'|
C:\MinGW\lib\libSDLmain.a(SDL_win32_main.o)||In function `cleanup':|
\Users\slouken\release\SDL\SDL-1.2.15\.\src\main\win32\SDL_win32_main.c|158|undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'|

**
```

Comment: What name mangling? You *will* have problems binding a temporary to `int&` in the catch. I would have used `const int&`, or just plain `int`.

Comment: @BoPersson funnily my G++ version (4.6) catches `throw 0` with `int&`.

Comment: Beetroot: general advice, not related to the question, but use `const string&` when passing strings around, unless in the few case where you know you want a copy.

Comment: Could you show us how you compile your source ? It seems that you are not linking with SDL, rather than having a problem with exceptions.

Comment: Ah yes you are correct, before it was compiling when I did not have the try/catch block but now it no longer does. I must have changed some setting. Darn it but thanks!

Comment: Thanks @J.N.  I was now able to fix it! I can't figure out how to give you rep though

Comment: I added an answer you can accept. You're welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error message, the problem is not related to exceptions in any way, but to your linking. You are using SDL headers but not linking to the SDL library, use the proper `-L` option.